# git status not showing untracked html file

Tags: git

I cloned an empty git directory in Terminal, then did a 'cd' to it. I created a new file named `index.html` but when I did '`git status`' it just shows message

```
"On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean"

If I try to add this file
$git add index.html
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:<br>
index.html
Use -f if you really want to add them.


But If I add 'untitled' text file to it then shows 

"On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:<
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    untitled.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)"
```

Why `index.html` file is not being tracked but the other '`untitled`' file it is able to track?

Comment: Have you have digit in terminal "git add ." for adding the file?

Comment: @PaolaG I tried "git add ." but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in the status message:

> The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>
> index.html

To find out where the ignore rule comes from, type `git check-ignore -v index.html`, and modify the ignore rules as necessary.

Comment: I did that but result seems to be same. $ git check-ignore index.html
index.html
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 untitled.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: Sorry, you need `-v` flag in the command to see where the ignore rule is coming from

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. I had to modify .gitignore_global file for this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your git repository may contain a hidden file called .gitignore which is used to ignore files which are no needed to add to the remote git repository as suggested by the user.

You can open the

> .gitignore

with a text editor and check whether it includes

> .html

files to be ignored.

Please refer https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: It doesnt have .gitignore file only a .git directory

Answer (score 0):

Read what the error message is telling you:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
index.html
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

You have a rule in a `.gitignore` file somewhere which is telling Git to ignore `index.html` and treat it as an untracked file.  Your first option would be to do what the message suggests:

```
git add -f index.html
```

This would override the ignore rule(s) and add the file anyway.  The other option would be to edit the `.gitignore` file responsible and change the rule.

But, before you try either of these, you should make sure that you should really be adding this file.  It seems that someone, possibly you, went to some trouble to prevent this file from being versioned.